# Dozer map to existing object non null fields

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

How can I map one object to another (existing) excluding null fields?

For example:

```
class A {
    String a1;
    String a2;
}

class B {
    String a1;
    String a2;
}
```

In A object I have non null field a1, on B object I have non null field a2. Is there any way to map object A to object B exclude field a2? Without custom converter and without excluding this field in mapping.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `map-null` attribute on `<mapping>` element in your `dozer-configuration-mapping.xml` file:

```
<mapping map-null="false">
  <class-a>your.package.A</class-a>
  <class-b>your.package.B</class-b>    
</mapping>
```